# how to set position of div according to table height

Tags: html, css

i make a table in which rows are dynamically inserted and then i make a div below table when table height increase due to more rows the div does not show ho i set the position of a div when increase table height the div automatically below the table?
here is my code:

```
<div id="table">
<table class="table table-bordered">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Description</th>
<th>Quantity</th>
<th>Price</th>
<th>Total</th>               
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
{% for invoice in invoices %}
<tr>
<td style="color:black;">{{ invoice.description }}</td> 
<td style="text-align:right; color:black;">{{ invoice.quantity }}</td>
<td style="text-align:right; color:black;">{{ invoice.unitPrice }}</td>
<td style="text-align:right; color:black;">{{ invoice.linetotal }}</td> 
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
<div style="width:243px; height:67px; float:right; margin:0px 215px 0; border:1px solid black;">
<h5>&nbsp;Invoice Total(USD)&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;{{invoiceamount}}</h5>
<h5>&nbsp;Paid to date&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;{{paidamount}}</h5>
<div class="horizontalRule2" runat="server"></div>
<h5>&nbsp;Invoice Total(USD)&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;{{balanceamount}}</h5>
</div>
```

and here is table css:

```
#table{
float: right;
height: 110px;
margin: 4px 215px 0;
width: 686px;
}
```

here is screenshot i want div show below the table:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try clearing the div#table or the totals div that is below:

```
div#table {
    clear:both;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think in this case I think you should stick with a table for those 2 cells as well, since somehow they are part of the tabulated data.

That means you could you just add them at

```
<div id="table">
<table class="table table-bordered">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Description</th>
<th>Quantity</th>
<th>Price</th>
<th>Total</th>               
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
{% for invoice in invoices %}
<tr>
<td style="color:black;">{{ invoice.description }}</td> 
<td style="text-align:right; color:black;">{{ invoice.quantity }}</td>
<td style="text-align:right; color:black;">{{ invoice.unitPrice }}</td>
<td style="text-align:right; color:black;">{{ invoice.linetotal }}</td> 
</tr>
{% endfor %}

<td colspan="3" style="text-align:right;"><h5>Invoice Total(USD)</h5></td>
<td style="text-align:right;"><h5>{{invoiceamount}}</h5></td>

<td colspan="3" style="text-align:right;"><h5>Paid to date(USD)</h5></td>
<td style="text-align:right;"><h5>{{balanceamount}}</h5></td>

</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```